# How do I inform dependent projects that an output must be copied local when they use ProjectReference?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have two projects, let's call them Project A and Project B.

Project A has a CopyToOutputDirectory content item, as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="MyExampleDependency.txt">
        <Link>MyFunOutputLocation\MyExampleDependency.txt</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Project B references Project A:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Shared\Project A.csproj">
        <Project>{My GUID here</Project>
        <Name>Project A</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

When I build Project B, it is smart enough to copy the .dll produced by Project A, as well as this text file, to the output. That is, I end up with something like this when I build Project B:

- `bin\Project A\Project A.dll`
- `bin\Project A\MyFunOutputLocation\MyExampleDependency.txt`
- `bin\Project B\Project A.dll`
- `bin\Project B\Project B.exe`
- `bin\Project B\MyFunOutputLocation\MyExampleDependency.txt`

I have a new dependency that I want to start generating in Project A; for example from a T4 transform. This could be a file I generate with an `<Exec` task, or a file generated by some custom target, or similar. For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Foo.tt">
        <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
        <OutputFilePath>$(OutDir)</OutputFilePath>
        <LastGenOutput>Foo.xml</LastGenOutput>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Now when I build I end up with something like this:

- `bin\Project A\Project A.dll`
- `bin\Project A\Foo.xml` <-- Not copied to Project B!
- `bin\Project A\MyFunOutputLocation\MyExampleDependency.txt`
- `bin\Project B\Project A.dll`
- `bin\Project B\Project B.exe`
- `bin\Project B\MyFunOutputLocation\MyExampleDependency.txt`

Note that the generated file which is required for `Project A.dll` to work is not being copied alongside that dll when it gets copied into Project B. How do I inform Project B that it needs to copy this file from Project A (without editing Project B's `.csproj` file)?

Comment: Project A is missing `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>` under `<Content Include="Foo.tt">`

Comment: @KMoraz that would copy Foo.tt, not Foo.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just a design-time `Foo.tt` output then it's as simple as expanding it in *Solution Explorer* and marking `Foo.txt` with appropriate *Copy To Output Directory*, just remember to mark it again if you ever change the extension as that'll delete and read it into the itemgroup losing the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadata.

If it's an outside task, then you need to hook into a delayed event (so it doesn't pollute explorer on load or even error on clean) in Project A and add it to `Content` preferably with a wildcard or exists condition. Keep in mind that event you choose needs to run after your custom task but before `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal`, e.g. if you create a file in `PreBuildEvent` of Project A and hook into `BeforeBuild` it won't work on clean build on Project B, you'd have to rebuild it again as `BeforeBuild` runs first and won't find anything at point of evaluation.

Project A.csproj

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\Bar.txt" Condition="Exists('$(OutputPath)\Bar.txt')">
            <Link>Bar.txt</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

**Edit**:

Try the following.

In `Project A` define a `Foo` target for delayed/ondemand inclusion of the T4 output.

```
<Target Name="Foo">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Foo.xml">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You said you're transforming on build, so somewhere in the project you have the `TextTemplating` import that defines `Transform` target and its dependencies.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

Hook into one of them, i.e. `AfterTransform`, after the `.targets` import.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AfterTransform>$(AfterTransform);Foo</AfterTransform>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That'll cover 90% of cases, the 9% left is building `Project B` directly in Visual Studio individually of `Project A`. The `Rebuild` would work out right thanks to `AfterTransform` but we need to hook into the `Import` since as you saw `BeforeBuild` is not executed as there are no changes and Visual Studio caches everything. We do this with `InitialTargets` on `Project A`.

```
<Project InitialTargets="Foo"
```

The final 1% is when you delete the `.xml` manually and build again as oppose to rebuild, but it's identical behaviour to deleting the `.pdb`, cached VS build will copy it again only if the `.dll` itself is missing or different.

Comment: So this causes a copy of the item over itself?

Comment: @BillyONeal it shouldn't, because of the PreserveNewest, depends where your custom task is writing to.

Comment: @BillyONeal worked for my test case. How/when/where do you create your dynamic files? Could you share your example (except for the T4 one since it works out of the box, no MSBuild trickery needed)?

Comment: T4 does not work out of the box -- it only works if you run the transformation at design time instead of during the build -- we need the transform to run in the build. When I ran my test the BeforeBuild target did not execute. (I tried adding an `<Error` task there but the build succeeded)

Comment: @BillyONeal that's... imposible? `BeforeBuild` must be called on generic `Build` of project references... Anyway, you're saying you just have the `<None Include="Foo.tt">` in the project but not the `<Content Include="Foo.xml">`, right? I'll give it a try, which method are you using to transform it on build? May be you can have a dummy/empty output, just so MSBuild evaluator can find the file and shove it into the `Content` itemgroup on load without any `Before*` event nonsense and then you can overwrite it with proper transformed one?

Comment: Except Build didn't get called either because MSBuild considers the entire project up to date because the content isn't considered part of the output. Yes, I'm saying there is an item for the .tt but no item for the generated file. We just set `<TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>` in a property to get that to happen; the relevant bits are on line 530 of `Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets`.

Comment: In order to run tt's as part of the build
First you need Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 SDK
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758
And then the Modelling SDK for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40754